# Database functions on RoR ActiveRecord Model layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, orm

I have a model called "Provision" with a table name "provisions". This model have a attributes with default values in database<strike>, because I don't know how to set value through ActiveRecord</strike>.

But the great problem is when the default value is null on database and I need to use database function like "GETDATE()" in RoR layer.

I'm wrong in my proporsal?

Comment: I'm forgotten explain there are many webservers and database server it's dedicated.

Comment: Maybe I'm don't explained rightly, I want to update activerecord with function database as a column value.

SQL that I want: UPDATE provinsions SET provisioned_at = GETDATE() WHERE id = ?;

Answer (score 0):

If your problem has to do with queries, then manipulating the `ActiveRecord::Base` objects wont be helpful. You can always execute custom SQL with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection('SQL STRING')`.

**Edit:**

Seems you want to run this on the server: `UPDATE provinsions SET provisioned_at = GETDATE() WHERE id = ?`. Well that's a piece of cake using ActiveRecord, you can refer to [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update).

```
# if you don't already have an AR::Base class with the same name (singularized) as your db table create it
class Provision < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this is not necessary, it specifies the db table name 
  # that AR already inferred from the class name
  self.table_name = 'provisions'
end

Provision.where(provisioned_at: nil).update_all provisioned_at: Time.zone.now
```

Comment: It's out specificacions and standardisation?